# How to find TOP N rows in sybase without using TOP and rowcount keywords?

Tags: sql, database, sybase, sybase-ase15

I need to find out first 1000 rows of a table without using top and rowcount. I must use where clause in my query. The query should look like this :

`select * from <table_name> where <condition>`

I do not have any good column that can be used in where clause.

Also I can't add a new column.

Comment: And why are the limitations?

Comment: what about `order by` and `limit 1000` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I limit the amount of results returned in Sybase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587135/how-do-i-limit-the-amount-of-results-returned-in-sybase)

Comment: My application is written in such a way that it takes condition as an input. Where is added by default. So. cant use limit as well.

Comment: @Gangaraju I dont think limit is part of sybase

Answer (score 0):

Using row_number with a literal value in the order by might be the solution you're looking for.

```
with n as (
    SELECT 
        neo.* 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) as [rn]
    FROM <table_name> neo
) 
SELECT 
    n.*
FROM n 
WHERE n.[rn] <= 1000 -- first 1000 rows
```

Comment: Cant chnage the select clause as well. Only thing I can input is the condition which will be added by the application after "where"

Comment: @Neo Can you share what the column names of your tables are, along with some sample data? BTW, it seems very strange that you're unable to only input the condition after the WHERE ... why is that?