# Alternative to Top 1 in Sybase DB

Tags: sql, sybase

I am using Sybase as our db and I have a query where I need to ensure that I only return one record. I have the following query that is returning more than one record and in Sybase you can't use MAX or TOP 1. What are some alternative ways to ensure that only 1 record is returned using the following query. I am also needing to do an "order by rate.effective_date desc" at the end of the query because I need to ensure the most recent date is returned also:

```
 select @sign_off_amount = -- dps minutes * dpy rate
               --dps duration, dps is in minutes
               convert(money,
               ( select oper_sign_off*1.0/60 from dps_parms where (@effective_dt between effective_dt and expires))
               *
               -- dpy rate/hr
               ( select rate.rate_amount
                   from drv_pay..work_type_sub_category wtsc
                       ,drv_pay..rate rate
                  where wtsc.work_type_sub_desc = 'SIGN OFF TIME'
                    and (wtsc.effective_date <= @effective_dt and wtsc.expire_date >= @effective_dt or wtsc.expire_date = NULL)
                    and wtsc.work_type_seq_nbr = rate.work_type_seq_nbr  and rate.full_part = 'F'
                    and (rate.effective_date <= @effective_dt and (rate.expire_date >= @effective_dt or rate.expire_date = NULL))))
```

I have tried to use SET ROWCOUNT 1 and SET ROWCOUNT 0 but cannot figure out where to put the syntax for that either.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: you have two subqueries (`select from dps_parms` / `select from work_type_sub_category,rate`) ... which one needs the `top 1` applied to it? or do both queries need a `top 1`? can the first subquery (`select from dps_params`) return more than one row and if so ... how do you plan to match the 'right' single row from both subqueries (ie, how do you determine which 2 rows to 'join' for the multiplication)?

Comment: Syvase ASE 16 has the TOP clause. What edition of Sybase are you using?

Comment: I'm using DBeaver and it's Sybase version 15. I am needing only one returned from the second subquery - the "select rate.rate_amount" query

Comment: Sybase **ASE** v 15 or Sybase **IQ** v 15?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587135/how-do-i-limit-the-amount-of-results-returned-in-sybase

Comment: assuming Sybase **ASE**, `set rowcount` is a standalone command so you would issue this before/after the `select @sign_off_amount = ....` query, ie, `set rowcount 1` then `select @sign_off_amount = .....` then `set rowcount 0`; the 3 can be submitted in the same batch or in individual batches (assuming your client maintains the same db connection across batches)